# Picture taken from external Bluetooth connected camera -> save to smartphone camera folder

Tags: bluetooth, camera, storage, automation

I am using MacroDroid and Tasker to automate multiple triggers/actions. I have managed to use this as a trigger for an example: a specific Android intent is received and then a photo is taken (even when the smartphone is locked) and the photo is sent as an attachment via email.

I want to do exactly the same with an external mini camera. When a trigger like an intent is received (for example in MacroDroid), the external camera will take a picture and will save it IN my smartphone's camera folder.

So, i am looking for a way **to communicate using software** from my Android smartphone (and wireless) with the external camera and achieve what is described in the previous paragraph. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: The original revision about camera recommendation has been posted to HardwareRecs.SE: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17965/364